# Custom deleters for std::shared_ptrs

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Is it possible to use a custom deleter after creating a `std::shared_ptr` without using `new`?

My problem is that object creation is handled by a factory class and its constructors & destructors are protected, which gives a compile error, and I don't want to use `new` because of its drawbacks.

To elaborate: I prefer to create shared pointers like this, which doesn't let you set a custom deleter (I think):

```
auto sp1 = make_shared<Song>(L"The Beatles", L"Im Happy Just to Dance With You");
```

Or I can create them like this, which does let met set a deleter through an argument:

```
auto sp2(new Song, MyDeleterFunc);
```

But the second one uses `new`, which AFAIK isn't as efficient as the top sort of allocation.

Maybe this is clearer: is it possible to get the benefits of `make_shared<>` as well as a custom deleter? Would that mean having to write an allocator?

Comment: Could you add some (pseudo-)code to explain what you need or otherwise elaborate? (I suspect an XY-Problem)

Comment: i don't understand your problem, ofc you are free to initialize shared_ptrs with your values, it doesn't have to be something returned by the new operator

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using custom deleter with std::shared\_ptr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340810/using-custom-deleter-with-stdshared-ptr)

Comment: The deleter is not part of the *type*, only of the *object*. So... no.

Comment: Care to elaborate, please? I'm new to smart pointers.

Comment: There are very few cases where a destructor has to be protected, especially when using shared pointers. Resist your urge to protect your class from downright malicious code like `delete sptr.get()`.

Comment: Mmm... that urge is very difficult to control once you've `protected`ized your constructors, for me at least!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `new` in your case as the design of `std::make_shared` to avoid an additional allocation can only work if `std::make_shared` can use it's *own* (internal) custom deleter to free to combined memory of the object and the `shared_count`.

You have to accept that with your own custom deleter you can not optimize away an allocation, but you should still use a `std::make_shared`-like wrapper to encapsulate the `new` for reasons of safe usage. This helps to avoid memory leaks in cases where the constructors of the object throw an exception and someone uses

```
template<typename T>
void f(const T&, const T&);

f( std::shared_ptr<X>(new X), std::shared_ptr<X>(new X) ); // possible leak
```

instead of

```
std::shared_ptr<X> make_X() { return std::shared_ptr<X>(new X); }
f( make_X(), make_X() ); // no leak
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you expand on why the second is better than the first? I don't see why there's a potential for leaks only in the first one.

Comment: In the second case each call to `make_X` makes sure that each pointer returned from `new` is immediately stored in a `std::shared_ptr` and so even in case of an exception, there is a `shared_ptr` which will delete the instance returned from `new`.

Comment: Is there anything reasonable? That will do the same as make_shared and will work with non-public destructors? IMHO, requirement to have public destructor defeats whole purpose of having shared pointers.

Comment: What is wrong with this approach: `make_shared<storage_with_deleter<T, D>>`, where `storage_with_deleter<T, D>` contains a `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T),alignof(T)> t;` and a `D d;`, on construction placement-news into the `t`, and on `~storage_with_deleter` invokes `d(static_cast<T*>(&t))`, then use aliasing constructor to turn it into a `shared_ptr<T>`.

Comment: @Yakk It might work, but since one point of `make_shared` is to be more efficient, returning another instance of `shared_ptr` through the aliasing constructor will prevent elision or other optimization (depending on context) and requiring an additional atomic ref-counter add and delete. In the end you'd have to benchmark it to see if it is really worth the additional complexity.

Comment: @DanielFrey Good point: the aliasing constructor takes by `const&` instead of by value (or rvalue ref).  That looks like a flaw, as it forces the atomic increment and decrement.  However, I doubt two atomic operations will out-cost a single extra memory allocation plus all the later cache misses.  I think writing `make_shared_with_deleter` should work, but I'm not sure what syntax to use...  Using forwarding tuples is ... awkward.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no form of [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) that takes a custom deleter.

If you need to return a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter then you'll have to take the performance hit.

Think about it: If you use `make_shared` then it will allocate a larger memory region that can store the reference count and your object together, and the placement new will be called. The `shared_ptr` returned from `make_shared` already has a custom deleter, one that calls your object's destructor explicitly and then frees the larger memory block.