# How to check the "type" of a Win32 handle at runtime

Tags: c++, winapi, c++11

I have to write a reference counted wrapper class in C++11 for Win32 handles like HFONT, HWND, HMODULE and so on. I want to use a single WinHandle class that implicitly casts to all handle types (which are all a void* typedef). Unfortunately all handles have different functions to destroy the underlying object for example DestroyWindow(), CloseHandle(), DeleteObject() and so forth, thus i'd need a different class for every handle-type to implement the appropriate destroy-function. (that would be 47 classes + base class including user objects, gdi objects and kernel objects)

So is there a way to determine at runtime of which "type" the handle is or rather which function needs to be called? (In the documentation I only found the isWindow() function)

I already thought about using RTTI or calling all delete-functions until one of them succeeds. RTTI won't work because all HANDLE types are typedefs of void* and thus the same. The latter might work, but all handles must be unique for it to work properly (no GDI handle can ever have the same value as a user handle or kernel handle) otherwise it might cause bugs and memory leaks

Comment: Handles are not necessarily a `void *` typedef. I believe it's `STRICT` that gives them their own types (and for good reason).

Comment: Don't many/most (all?) of those close/delete functions take a `HANDLE` and return a `BOOL`? If so, you could pass the deleting function to the constructor of your handle wrapper as a `BOOL (*deleter)(HANDLE)`, store it in your wrapper object and call it when appropriate.

Comment: NtQueryObject may helps you, but if I remember correctly dont work with USER nor GDI handles.

Comment: Even if such a detection function existed, it wouldn't help you. Suppose `IsWindow()` and `IsFont()` both return `TRUE`. (Which is possible, because the only guarantee is that no two windows will have the same handle, but a window handle might be equal to a font handle.) You still don't know whether you have a window handle or a font handle. You need to know what kind of handle you have. (The `STRICT` macro may help.)

Comment: You'd probably want a `WinHandle<HFONT>`, `WinHandle<HWND>` etc. But why do you want a refcounted wrapper? There's already `DuplicateHandle`.

Comment: I am baffled as to why Win32 doesn't have a function called IsConsoleHandle.

Answer (score 2):

If the only thing you're looking for is a reference counted handle, why not just use `shared_ptr` ?

E.g :

```
shared_ptr<void> file( CreateFile(L"la.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL), CloseHandle);   

DWORD written;
WriteFile(file.get(), //get handle
          "ABC\r\n", 
          5,
          &written, 
          NULL);
```

It doesn't have a big foot print int your code and you won't have to write 40 classes.

---

You can avoid passing the relevant close function each time by defining some function for each *type* of closing e.g :

```
auto make_handle_CloseHandle = [](HANDLE h){ return  (shared_ptr<void>(h,CloseHandle)); };

auto file = make_handle_CloseHandle(CreateFile(L"la.txt", /*same ...*/));

DWORD written;
WriteFile(   file.get(), //get handle
            "ABC\r\n", 
            5,
            &written, 
            NULL);
```

And put it in some header file under a relevant namespace that way you won't have to type the close function's name each time and users of those functions will know which function is called (according to the `make_handle_*` name) which might make thing safer than trying to automagically identify the handle's type just by the handle.

Comment: thx for your answer, I will definitely look into that as well. If you ask me it's a bit bulky to pass the destroyer function to the ctor everytime, but I'm sure it would be better to utilize std::shared_ptr in some way, as it's arc algorithm will most likely be faster than mine. Maybe I can derive from shared_ptr and use the STRICT macro to distinguish beetween different handle-types

Comment: @Cody227 you can easily avoid passing the destroyer function each time, please see my edit.

Comment: This answer needs some [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) love.

Comment: @rubenvb I'd be happy to improve the answer but as the documentation states _This function is typically used to replace the construction std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(args...)) of a shared pointer from the raw pointer returned by a call to **new**._ And in this case we're not creating a raw pointer by calling `new` but by using some WIN32 function. Another thing (that is probably related) is that I didn't find a way to supply a custom deleter when using `make_shared` (probably because it assumes `new` and `delete` are needed)

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I am mistaken (e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19599749/custom-deleters-for-stdshared-ptrs) explains it quite well...). Sorry for the noise!

Comment: @rubenvb NP :) and thanks for linking to that question.

Answer (score 2):

Since the failure result for CreateFile is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (-1) I'm not certain this is a good solution all in all.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea

Rather than use something intended to refer to a memory address, implementing some sort of shared_resource or unique_resource type, which accepts template arguments or a single argument that encapsulates the characteristics of the wrapped type is probably the way to go.

Mine looks something like this:

```
template <typename TRAITS>
struct SharedHandle
{
....
}
```

and is used like this:

```
struct TestTraits
{
    using HandleType = int;
    static constexpr HandleType INVALID = 0;
    static void Close(HandleType& h)
    {
        h = INVALID;
    }
};

using SharedHandleTestType = SharedHandle<TestTraits>;


TEST(ClvLib_SharedHandle_Tests, SharedHandle_default)
{
    auto tt = SharedHandleTestType();

    EXPECT_FALSE(tt);
}

TEST(ClvLib_SharedHandle_Tests, SharedHandle_good)
{
    auto tt = SharedHandleTestType(1);

    EXPECT_TRUE(tt);
}

TEST(ClvLib_SharedHandle_Tests, SharedHandle_use)
{
    auto tt = SharedHandleTestType(1);

    auto result = [](int t)->int {return t + 1; }(tt);
    auto expected = tt.Get() + 1;

    EXPECT_EQ(expected, result);
}

TEST(ClvLib_SharedHandle_Tests, SharedHandle_copy1)
{
    auto tt = SharedHandleTestType(1);
    auto t2 = tt;

    EXPECT_TRUE(tt);
    EXPECT_TRUE(t2);

    tt = 0;

    EXPECT_FALSE(tt);
    EXPECT_TRUE(t2);
}

TEST(ClvLib_SharedHandle_Tests, SharedHandle_copy2)
{
    auto tt = SharedHandleTestType(1);
    auto t2 = tt;

    EXPECT_TRUE(tt);
    EXPECT_TRUE(t2);

    tt = 0;

    EXPECT_FALSE(tt);
    EXPECT_TRUE(t2);

    t2.Release();

    EXPECT_FALSE(tt);
    EXPECT_FALSE(t2);
}
```

For Windows file handles:

```
struct WinHandleTraits_IHV
{
    using HandleType = HANDLE;
    static constexpr HandleType INVALID = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    static void Close(HandleType& h)
    {
        CloseHandle(h);
    }
};

using WinFileHandle = SharedHandle<WinHandleTraits_IHV>;
```