# Destructor for a template container

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm building a Java-like ArrayList class in C++ just for practice (yes, I know `std::vector` and other great alternatives exist).

I understand that the `new` keyword is paired with the `delete` keyword and `malloc, calloc, realloc` is paired with `free`.

So, let's say I have a class `ArrayList` that contains pointers to some generic type `T`. In other words, the underlying array in my `ArrayList` looks like this

`T* array` where `T` is some `template <typename T>`.

I'm defining my destructor for `ArrayList` and I have a few questions..

1. The destructor should be responsible for freeing all the memory stored in the `ArrayList`. But I don't know if the `T*`s that it's holding  were created using a `new` or a `malloc`-type, so how do I dealloc them? I feel like running into this problem is a sign of an anti-pattern, so any advice would be appreciated!
2. The `ArrayList` itself can be instantiated in two ways

On the stack...

```
ArrayList arr;
```

or on the heap...

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
```

If it was initialized on the stack, I don't have to worry about managing `arr`'s memory, but can I assume that its destructor will be called before the `arr` itself is somehow deallocated?

If it was initialized on the heap, does calling `delete arr` call its destructor *and* deallocate `arr` itself?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) Why are you writing `ArrayList`, if `std::vector` is exactly that? 2) Typically, container classes manage their own memory, hence you know how memory for `array` was allocated. Hint: you should avoid using `malloc` where possible, due to the fact, that it doesn't invoke constructors, where `new` does. 3) Typically, classes shouldn't care how they were allocated. It changes nothing for class internal structure.

Comment: `malloc`/`free` don't construct or destruct objects and are not appropriate for most class types. `new`/`delete` does.

Comment: As mentioned in the original post, I'm doing it for practice. I don't expect `malloc` to invoke constructors, I'm assuming that the `ArrayList`, will store pointers to pre-constructed objects/primitives.

Comment: Yes, that's why the class interface doesn't use `malloc/free`, I'm using it internally to build a resizable array class.

Comment: *deconstructor* -- The term is *destructor*, not *deconstructor*.

Comment: @Carpetfizz There's no reason to use `malloc` to create arrays, `new` is perfectly capable of it as well.

Comment: cant you just do a for loop and then `delete arraylist[i]` ?

Comment: @ChadK sure, but that's only assuming that the `T*` point to an object created using the `new` keyword. What if I'm storing pointers to blocks that were `malloc`'d?

Comment: @Carpetfizz *But I don't know if the T that it's holding were created using a new or a malloc-type, so how do I dealloc them?*  -- You don't know, unless the client tells you how to deallocate.  The client could have just stored an address of a non-dynamically created object, or an object created with an operating system API call (i.e. LocalAlloc from Windows).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie would you suggest that it's good design to restrict the usage of `ArrayList` to objects that were created using the `new` keyword? What are they called? What about primitives?

Comment: @Carpetfizz -- You can do what the smart pointer classes `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` do.  Assume that the "deleter" is `delete`, and have your class have a custom deleter supplied by the client.  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340810/using-custom-deleter-with-stdshared-ptr)

Comment: Do you mind linking to how to accomplish the last part with the template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The deconstructor should be responsible for freeing all the memory stored in the `ArrayList`. But I don't know if the `T*`s that it's holding were created using a new or a `malloc`-type, so how do I dealloc them? I feel like running into this problem is a sign of an anti-pattern, so any advice would be appreciated!

You should not be taking in any `T*`s. You are correct that you have no way to determine how such pointers should be freed. You should handle the allocations yourself (as `std::vector` does), in which case you no longer have this problem.

> If it was initialized on the stack, I don't have to worry about managing `arr`'s memory, but can I assume that its deconstructor will be called before the `arr` itself is somehow deallocated?

Yes. When a local variable goes out of scope, the object (if any) is destroyed. This involves calling its destructor (again, if any).

> If it was initialized on the heap, does calling `delete arr` call its deconstructor and deallocate `arr` itself?

Yes. `delete arr` calls `arr`'s destructor (again, if any) and frees the reserved memory.

Comment: Thank you for clearing the confusion! I have a question about your first point. What do you mean by handing the allocations myself? A user is constructing the objects however they wish and just giving it to `ArrayList` to store.

Comment: @Carpetfizz  If objects are being given to `ArrayList` then you need to store them by copy constructing them into the `ArrayList` .The `ArrayList` is now responsible for deleting the copies.

Comment: @RichardCritten  gotcha thanks! Is this what the standard libraries do (in Java and std::vector)?

Comment: @Carpetfizz  That is how `std::vector` works.  Java however has a completely different mechanism based on every object being a reference (with reference counting) and storing the reference in the container. and using garbage collection in-place of explicit destruction.

Comment: @RichardCritten  thanks again. So if someone stores objects in std::vector and destroys std::vector they should expect to manually delete all the objects they ended up storing in std::vector right?

Comment: @Carpetfizz If you have a `std::vector<Foo>`, then the vector will take care of destroying any `Foo` objects in its destructor. If you have a `std::vector<Foo*>`, then when that vector is destroyed, the pointed-to `Foo` objects will not be.

Comment: @Carpetfizz last comment (cos I think you need to read a book).  Objects are put into a `std::vector` by copying them.  The `std::vector` is responsible for deleting these copies.  What happens to the originals is the responsibility of the caller. Book list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282

Comment: @RichardCritten FWIW, Java does not use reference counting (or at least not exclusively). Reference counting cannot handle circular references, but Java does handle them.

Comment: @hvd I had a few lines to describe the differences in memory model between Java and C++ and how this affects the containers in each language.  Please cut me some slack.